# CSS - diagonal split hover effect

Tags: css, hover, diagonal

Is possible to do diagonal splitted background (as on the image) only by css (without background image)?[Diagonal hover effect in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWpqQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ggxan18/)?

If this is the desired style, you can find more info on [*w3schools*](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
.btn {
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(228,245,252,1) 0%,rgba(191,232,249,1) 50%,rgba(159,216,239,1) 51%,rgba(42,176,237,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot at gradients.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah- use gradiant, if you dont want background img.

you can use this generator if you want http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/